# DJANGO template tags in plain text not displaying

Tags: html, django

I am making an app that displays questions. The question model has a text field and an image field. Each question has a template that is stored in my database in the text field. My problem is when I want to access images from the model, template tags are displayed as text and not rendering. My code:

```
# question model
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField()
    question_image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/images/questions', blank=true)

# question view
def question(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'questiontemplate.html', {'question': question})

# template
{% extends 'base.html %}
{% load static %}

{% autoscape off %}
{{ question.question_text }}
{% endautoscape %}

# in my database:
question.question_text = '<p> some html
                         {{ question.question_image.url }}
                         some html </p>'
question.question_image = 'image.png'
```

This works fine and renders the html perfectly except the template tag is not rendered and does not not give the image url

I want this to be the output:

```
Some html
static/images/questions/image.png
some html
```

But instead this is the output:

```
some html
{{ question.question_image.url }}
some html
```

Any suggestions to how the template tags could be render from the database text would be much appreciated.
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't know that the content in your model field is itself a model. The template can't know that. The only way to make this work is to treat that field itself as a template, and render it manually.

You could do that with a method on the model:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def render_question(self):
        template = Template(self.question_text)
        context = Context({'question': self})
        rendered = template.render(context)
        return mark_safe(rendered)
```

Now you can call it in your template:

```
{{ question.render_question }}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you very much!